# Rails: translation file not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to translate the majority of an application I am working on to Dutch. I created a du.yml file and am formatting it in the same way my en.yml file is formatted (to be sure):

```
en:
  Hello: "Hello World"
```

When outputting the en.yml the application populates the text properly. However when I load the du.yml it gives me the translation not found span wrap around the desired translated material.

The steps I have taken to set this up are as follows -

added to `application_controller.rb`:

```
before_filter :set_locale

def set_locale
 I18n.locale = params[:lang] if params[:lang].present?
end
```

This allows me to pass a param in the query-string to determine what language to use.

I then did as shown up top and added values to be translated on both the en.yml and du.yml files

I then call the values from the respective files with (for example) `<%= t :hello %>`. When I set english as the param (`?lang=en`), everything works great. However, when I put `?lang=du`, I get what I mentioned before - the dreaded span tag of missing translation.

Any ideas on what I may have done wrong? Thanks!

Oh yeah..and both files are in the same directory (config/locales)

Comment: And the `en.yml` starts with `en:` and the `du.yml` with `du:`?

Comment: Yes both files respectively have the appropriate formatting

Comment: did you restart rails server after adding the new locale file?

Comment: Tried that it works. That makes total sense. Even though I can make constant changes, the server still would need to initially load the new locale file...Thanks house9! You deserve the rep of a real answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learned that, although rails development allows you to make changes on the fly, file additions require a server re-load. Thanks to [house9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/317989/house9) for the clarification.